# sklearn Gaussian Naive Bayes - why "Gaussian"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, naivebayes

I understand the Bayes theorem but don't understand what is the "Gaussian" part in the classifier. Why is it called "Gaussian"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the setting of [`sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html). The `fit` method takes an `x` and a `y`, and tries to fit them. They correspond to instances of random variables *X* and *y*, and *y* takes some values *c ∈ C*. So, we can estimate *f(X|C = c)*. Of course, we are interested in *P(C = c|X)*. If you recall Bayes' Theorem,

*P(A | B) = P(B | A)P(A) / P(B)*,

we need the apriori distribution of *X* for this reversal. In [gaussian naive bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Gaussian_naive_Bayes), this is assumed to be a normal distribution.

Comment: It's worth adding that the other term for a normal distribution is _Gaussian distribution_, and hence the name.